# Magento extension to expose new SOAP API endpoint

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.6

I'm integrating Magento with a Ruby application and I'm using the XML-RPC API, but I'm facing an issue which I could only solve modifying Magento API code.

The thing is, I want to list the ProductAttribute but I need the "label" field comes along with the results
The default API response does not include the 'label' field, which I need:

```
array
  0 =>
    array
      'attribute_id' => string '71' (length=2)
      'code' => string 'name' (length=4)
      'type' => string 'text' (length=4)
      'required' => string '1' (length=1)
      'scope' => string 'store' (length=5)
```

This would solve my problem if I had access to every Magento store I'm integrating with [How to extend Magento API catalog_product.list to include more product information XML-RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796845/how-to-extend-magento-api-catalog-product-list-to-include)...

**But** I need to integrate with *any* Magento store and I don't have access to every Magento store server.

The integration should be transparent to the Magento store owner, the ideal would be having only the xml-rpc username and api key and consume their API, but since the API does not provide everything I need I'd need a practical solution, like installing an extension on every store that will integrate with my app. Which leads me to the following:

Is it possible to build a Magento extension which can expose a new API Endpoint that returns all the information I need? Or is there any other solution for this scenario?

Comment: Edited as per [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Comment: And... what's the question?

Comment: I want to know if I can build a Magento extension to expose a new API Endpoint that returns all the information I need or if there any other solution

Answer (score -1):

You can make a poolback file changing just the file you want, assume you can solve your problem using the solution of the link, the orientation is just to change some lines of the file: \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Api.php

You can create a module witch overrides this Model and make the job, you can create a new module with a new method of API to catch what you need, i'll explain some of this solutions:
Creating a poolback, just take the file:

```
\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Api.php
```

And copy and put on:

```
\app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Api.php
```

So you can change what you want, can pack it and send to your customers.

Can apply this solution creating a new API Model and new method check this [link](http://inchoo.net/magento/extending-the-magento-api/).

And finally overrides the Api model from product, check this [link](https://inchoo.net/magento/how_to_override_magento_model_classes/).

Comment: Hey thanks! But the major problem is I do not have the access the customers Magento servers, the integration should be transparent to the Magento store owner
The goal is to integrate with any Magento store and the ideal scenario would be having only the xml-rpc username and api key and consume that the store API but since the default API does not provide everything I need I'm looking for a solution that can be very practical do the store owner, like installing a extension and providing the xml-rpc access information

Comment: Yes, unfortunally it's impossible do that without install a extension or something. With the solution i've said you can make that. You make the poolback file, and make a tar with the full path, so the customer just put the file on the root folder from project and untar it.